# Error in $A.getCallback() [Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]] Failing descriptor:

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am getting this error when running a LWC in flow Error in $A.getCallback() [Error during LWC component connect phase:

> [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]] Failing descriptor:
> {markup://flowruntime:flowRuntimeV2}

```
import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';
export default class FlowCarousel extends LightningElement {
    @api ImageURLs;
    @api Headers;
    @api Descriptions;
    @api AltText;
    @api carouselTitle;
    @track items = [];

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("initializing FlowCarousel");
        console.log("ImageURLs is:" + this.ImageURLs);
        console.log("Descriptions is:" + this.Descriptions);
        console.log("AltText is:" + this.AltText);
        let items = [];
        let index = 0;
        console.log("Headers is: " + this.Headers);
        
        this.Headers.forEach(header => {
          items.push({
            header: header,
            src: this.ImagURLs[index],
            description: this.Descriptions[index],
            alttext: this.AltText[index], 
            uniqueId: this.AltText[index] + " + " + index     
          });
          console.log("items is: " + items);
          index + 1;
        });
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>       
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-size_xx-large" >
        <div class="slds-text-align_center">{carouselTitle}            
            <lightning-carousel > 
                <template for:each={items} for:item="item">                              
                   <lightning-carousel-image key={item.uniqueId}             
                    src = {item.src}
                    header = {item.header}
                    description = {item.description}
                    alternative-text = {item.alttext}
                    href = "javascript:void(0);">
                </lightning-carousel-image> 
            </template>                                         
            </lightning-carousel>        
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@api` properties must be named starting with a lowercase character, because they will be [kebab-cased](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_names) in the parent template. In fact, it is a general best practice to always [camelCase](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/camelCase.html) all properties of a class. This specific error states you're trying to access index 0 of an undefined variable, which it must be, as there is no way to pass in the Headers attribute.

```
@api imageUrls;
@api headers;
@api descriptions;
@api altTexts;
@api carouselTitle;
@track items = [];
```

Also, you could be using an Array.map function to make things a bit more legible in your code (also, better performance):

```
this.items = 
  [...Array(this.headers.length).keys()].map(index => ({
    header: this.headers[index],
    src: this.imageUrls[index],
    description: this.descriptions[index],
    alttext: this.altTexts[index],
    uniqueId: `${this.altText[index]} - ${index}`
  }));
```

Comment: got it to work it ended up being a missing the letter "e" on this.ImagURLs[index] it should read this.ImageURLs[index]